# How to exclude values in django aggregation?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have done this:

```
groups = group1.objects.filter(User=request.user, Company=company_details.pk, ledgergroups__Creation_Date__gte=selectdatefield_details.Start_Date, ledgergroups__Creation_Date__lte=selectdatefield_details.End_Date).exclude(group_Name__icontains='Capital A/c')
groups_cb = groups.annotate(
            closing = Coalesce(Sum('ledgergroups__Closing_balance'), 0),
            opening = Coalesce(Sum('ledgergroups__Balance_opening'), 0),
        )
```

I want to perform aggregation in 'closing' and 'opening' by interchanging the negative values of annotation...

I mean the negative value which will come through annotation in 'closing', that value should be added with the aggregated value of 'opening'....

For example:

if the values of closing are 2500,5000,-8000
The total value will be 7500(aggregated value)

and -8000 will be added in the aggregated value of 'opening'.

Do anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Case` and `When`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) within a `Sum` annotation:

```
Sum(
    Case(
        When(
            another_model__field_value__lt=0,
            then=F('another_model__field_value'),
        ),
        default=F('another_model__other_field_value'),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
)
```